# vba table column reference instead of cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in excel. I add column and name them. the code works with cell reference.  however if i use Range("tablename[columnname]"), i get an error when i add formulas.

the first part works ok. i can add colums and name them.

```
Sub insertTableColumn()

Dim lst As ListObject

Dim currentSht As Worksheet


'The below add columns on a table and rename them

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FBL5NSheet")

Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("FBL5NTable")

ColumnNames = Array("FBL5NDocNrCalc", "FBL5NRefCalc", "FBL5NDocNrCalcCut")

For iLoop = 0 To UBound(ColumnNames)

    Set oLC = lst.ListColumns.Add

    oLC.Name = ColumnNames(iLoop)

Next

End Sub
```

---

i have issues with the second part. it works with cell reference. but not with

```
Range("tablename[columnname]").
```

i tried the below and i got an error.

```
Range("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNrCalc]").Formula = "=IF(("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr"]) <> ""),("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]") & ("FBL5N[FBL5NCcode]") & ("FBL5N[FBL5NTradingPartner]") & ("FBL5N[FBL5NDocCur]")), "")"
```

the below code work with cell reference. if i use table reference i get an error. How can i do the below using Range("tablename[columnname]")

---

```
Sub FillCalculainInColumn()

'enter formulas
Range("O2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF([@FBL5NDocNr]<>"""",([@FBL5NDocNr]*1&[@FBL5NCcode]&[@FBL5NTradingPartner]&[@FBL5NDocCur]),"""")"

Range("P2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF([@FBL5NRef]<>"""",([@FBL5NRef]*1&[@FBL5NCcode]&[@FBL5NTradingPartner]&[@FBL5NDocCur]),"""")"

Range("Q2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT([@[FBL5NDocNrCalc ]],18)"
'fill formulas to last row

Range("O2:Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

End Sub
```

---

i do only the below, and i get an error, i wonder if i need more than this

Sub FillCalculainInColumn()

Range("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNrCalc]").Formula = _ "=IF(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]<>"""",CONCATENATE(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr],F‌​BL5N[FBL5NCcode],FBL‌​5N[FBL5NTradingPartn‌​er],FBL5N[FBL5NDocCu‌​r]),"""")"

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your quotation marks are all over the place (and in the wrong places):

```
Range("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNrCalc]").Formula = _
    "=IF(("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr"]) <> ""),("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]")&"FBL5N[FBL5NCcode]")&("FBL5N[FBL5NTradingPartner]")&("FBL5N[FBL5NDocCur]")), "")"
```

For instance, if we look only at this one component:

```
"FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr"]
```

Clearly, that's imbalanced as you've got one inside the closing bracket, which is almost surely an error.

I am not sure you even need quotation marks in this case at all, **untested**, but try:

```
Range("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNrCalc]").Formula = _
    "=IF(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]<>"""",FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]&FBL5N[FBL5NCcode]&FBL5N[FBL5NTradingPartner]&FBL5N[FBL5NDocCur], """")"
```

You need to double-up the quotation marks in some places (wherever you're expressing an empty string *inside* the formula string) and omit quotation marks in other places (where you're referring to table columns). I also don't think you need the parentheses around each of the column names.

Using `CONCATENATE` might be clearer, too:

```
Range("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNrCalc]").Formula = _
    "=IF(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]<>"""",CONCATENATE(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr],FBL5N[FBL5NCcode],FBL5N[FBL5NTradingPartner],FBL5N[FBL5NDocCur]),"""")"
```

Comment: thank for reply. When i try i get an error "Compile error , syntax error".

Comment: @ftc If you get compile error, what line is raising the error. This compiles on my end, so most likely you mistyped something.

Comment: I made a small revision because I think there were too many parentheses still.

Comment: Do i need anything more than the below, i get error still ....  Sub FillCalculainInColumn()

Range("FBL5N[FBL5NDocNrCalc]").Formula = _
    "=IF(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr]<>"""",CONCATENATE(FBL5N[FBL5NDocNr],FBL5N[FBL5NCcode],FBL5N[FBL5NTradingPartner],FBL5N[FBL5NDocCur]),"""")"

End Sub

Comment: when I copy & paste that into the VBE, it compiles but I notice some errant characters in at least 2 spots, http://imgur.com/mQo5meF though this would cause a runtime error not a compile error. Please continue to *update* your question with the code you're actually trying to implement, comments are not meant to contain much code as it is hard to read them that way.